# Efficiently replacing strings within an HTML block in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, mootools

I am using Javascript(with Mootools) to dynamically build a large page using HTML "template" elements, copying the same template many times to populate the page. Within each template I use string keywords that need to be replaced to create the unique IDs. I'm having serious performance issues however in that it takes multiple seconds to perform all these replacements, especially in IE. The code looks like this:

```
var fieldTemplate = $$('.fieldTemplate')[0];
var fieldTr = fieldTemplate.clone(true, true);
fieldTr.removeClass('fieldTemplate');
replaceIdsHelper(fieldTr, ':FIELD_NODE_ID:', fieldNodeId);
parentTable.grab(fieldTr);
```

replaceIdsHelper() is the problem method according to IE9's profiler. I've tried two implementations of this method:

```
// Retrieve the entire HTML body of the element, replace the string and set the HTML back.
var html = rootElem.get('html').replace(new RegExp(replaceStr, 'g'), id);
rootElem.set('html', html);
```

and

```
// Load the child elements and replace just their IDs selectively
rootElem.getElements('*').each(function(elem) {
    var elemId = elem.get('id');
    if (elemId != null) elemId = elemId.replace(replaceStr, id);
    elem.set('id', elemId)
});
```

However, both of these approaches are extremely slow given how many times this method gets called(about 200...). Everything else runs fine, it's only replacing these IDs which seems to be a major performance bottleneck. Does anyone know if there's a way to do this efficiently, or a reason it might be running so slow? The elements start hidden and aren't grabbed by the DOM until after they're created so there's no redrawing happening.

By the way, the reason I'm building the page this way is to keep the code clean, since we need to be able to create new elements dynamically after loading as well. Doing this from the server side would make things much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some things you can do to optimise it - and what @nizan tomer said is very good, the pseudo templating is a good pattern.

First of all.

```
var fieldTemplate = $$('.fieldTemplate')[0];
var fieldTr = fieldTemplate.clone(true, true);
```

you should do this as:

```
var templateHTML = somenode.getElement(".fieldTemplate").get("html"); // no need to clone it.
```

the template itself should/can be like suggested, eg:

```
<td id="{id}">{something}</td>
```

only read it once, no need to clone it for every item - instead, use the new Element constructor and just set the innerHTML - notice it lacks the `<tr> </tr>`.

if you have an object with data, eg:

```
var rows = [{
    id: "row1",
    something: "hello"
}, {
    id: "row2",
    something: "there"
}];

Array.each(function(obj, index) {
    var newel = new Element("tr", {
        html: templateHTML.substitute(obj)
    });
    // defer the inject so it's non-blocking of the UI thread:
    newel.inject.delay(10, newel, parentTable);
    // if you need to know when done, use a counter + index
    // in a function and fire a ready.
});
```

alternatively, use document fragments:

```
Element.implement({
    docFragment: function(){
        return document.createDocumentFragment();
    }
});

(function() {
    var fragment = Element.docFragment();  

    Array.each(function(obj) {
        fragment.appendChild(new Element("tr", {
            html: templateHTML.substitute(obj)
        }));
    });

    // inject all in one go, single dom access
    parentTable.appendChild(fragment);
})();
```

I did a jsperf test on both of these methods:
http://jsperf.com/inject-vs-fragment-in-mootools

surprising win by chrome by a HUGE margin vs firefox and ie9. also surprising, in firefox individual injects are faster than fragments. perhaps the bottleneck is that it's TRs in a table, which has always been dodgy.

For templating: you can also look at using something like mustache or underscore.js templates.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot of good advice. I can definitely speed things up this way.

I think my approach of building the whole page in JS was just too client-intensive though, we do have to support IE7 and users could have slow computers too... So what I'm going to do is compromise by making a few JSP tags to populate the page with the starting data, and then use those same tags to create the templates that I can copy for new entries.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but it sounds to me that the problem is with the indexing of the dom tree.

First of all, do you must use ids or can you manage with classes? since you say that the replacement of the id is the main issue.

Also, why do you clone part of the dom tree instead of just inserting a new html?
You can use the substitute method of String (when using MooTools), like so:

```
var template = '<div id="{ID}" class="{CLASSES}">{CONTENT}</div>';
template.substitute({ID: "id1", CLASSES: "c1 c2", CONTENT: "this is the content" });
```

you can read more about it here [http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/String#String:substitute](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/String#String%3asubstitute)

Then, just take that string and put it as html inside a container, let's say:

```
$("container_id").set("html", template);
```

I think that it might improve the efficiency since it does not clone and then index it again, but I can't be sure.  give it a go and see what happens.